# Expectation of a multipart function of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $Q$ be a random variable with known CDF: $P(Q \leq q) = F_{Q}(q)$, say, exponential with known $\lambda$.
Which is the expectation of $R$, $E[R]$, and the corresponding CDF $F_{R}(r)$, where $R$ is:
\begin{equation}
 R = 
 \begin{cases}
 Q & \text{ with } 1-p \\
 0 & \text{ with } p
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $0 < p < 1$. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean $R=XQ$, where $X$ is $0$ with probability $p$ and $1$ with probability $1-p$ being independent of $Q$?

Comment: i haven't that in mind but if this is the case?

Comment: Then what exactly does $R=Q$ with $1-p$ mean? Does it mean that $P(R=Q)=1-p$? In that case you cannot say anything in general about $E[R]$.

Comment: Our thought was that someone give us Q with exponential distribution and with probability 1-p and give us 0 with probability p.

Comment: Ok, then you need an assumption that the decision is independent of $Q$, otherwise you can't say anything. And under the independency assumption then you're in the case I described in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X\sim\mathrm{bin}(1,1-p)$ be a binomial variable that is independent of $Q$, i.e.
$$
P(X=0)=p,\quad P(X=1)=1-p.
$$
Now, define $R=X\cdot Q$, then $R$ has the following interpretation:
$$
R=
\begin{cases}
Q&\text{if }X=1,\\
0&\text{if }X=0.
\end{cases}
$$

Then you just use what you know to derive properties of $R$ and here the independecy is a *crucial* assumption. For example
$$
E[R]=E[X\cdot Q]=E[X]\cdot E[Q]
$$
due to the independency of $X$ and $Q$. Now plug in the mean of $Q$ and $X$. Use similar reasoning to obtain $F_R(r)$.

Comment: Some parts of this answer assume that $\Pr(Q=0)=0$.

Comment: @Did: Yep, you're right - fixed :)

Comment: The modified version avoids the problem of a possible atom at zero. +1.